# Apply Array.map with Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

How would I write the following code correctly in Swift 4.2:

```
let navStack = ["root", "page1", "page3"]
let route = ["root", "page1", "page2", "page3"]
let routeTags =
[
    "root": ["root"],
    "page1": ["page1", "page2"],
    "page3": ["page3"]
]
let r = navStack.map({ routeTags[$0] }).joined(separator: "/")
```

The current code doesn't compile (ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'). The code should produce a string with the dictionary values mapped according to the keys in `navStack`.

Comment: I think replacing the map with mapValues will do the job.

Comment: What you want as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The result of `routeTags[$0]` is an optional and must be unwrapped (safely with `compactMap`).
2. The `joined` expression must be moved **into** the closure because the second item is an array.

---

```
let navStack = ["root", "page1", "page3"]
let route = ["root", "page1", "page2", "page3"]
let routeTags =
    [
        "root": ["root"],
        "page1": ["page1", "page2"],
        "page3": ["page3"]
]
let r = navStack.compactMap{ routeTags[$0]?.joined(separator: "/") }
```

Or you have to use `joined` twice if you want one single string:

```
let r = navStack.compactMap{ routeTags[$0]?.joined(separator: "/") }.joined(separator: "/")
```

Comment: Your solution sounds plausible but I get another error for it: `cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String]]' with an index of type 'Character'`

Comment: That's impossible if you are using **exactly** the code in my answer.

Comment: You're right! Noticed the mistake in my code! Thank you!